# Move tab on left side of page to right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab that is currently residing on the left side of my screen. What I would like to do is move it to the right side and also move it up some. I will post what I have for it residing on the left side:

**CSS**

```
#feedback {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 250px;
        margin-left: -3px;
        margin-bottom: -3px;
    }

    #feedback-tab {
        float: right;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        width: 120px;
        height: 42px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-left: -42px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }

    #feedback-tab:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="feedback">
    <div id="feedback-tab">Feedback</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a JSBin or JsFiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/89fjamf8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

CSS:

```
#feedback {
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 150px;
        height: 250px;
        margin-left: -3px;
        margin-bottom: -3px;
    }

    #feedback-tab {
        float: right;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        width: 120px;
        height: 42px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-right: -42px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

    #feedback-tab:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    }
```

AND HTML:

```
<div id="feedback">
    <div id="feedback-tab">Feedback</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#feedback {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            height: 250px;
            margin-right: -3px;
            margin-bottom: -3px;
        }
```

Also, not knowing the parent of this element can difficult the answer, in my opinion.